# Manga about a princess who is protected by twelve elite warriors, each wielding a distinctive sword

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There is a princess who is protected by twelve elite warriors, each wielding a distinctive sword. However, one of the guardians betrays the princess, leading to a crisis. The story follows the princess and a protagonist who gets isekai'd in this world. I believe the genre is historical fantasy.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was mostly in  black n white, hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Arata: The Legend](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/lbxadma/arata-kangatari)***...?

> Every 30 years, a new princess is chosen from the Hime family to serve the Hayagami. The time has come again, but over these past years, records state not a single female has been born, save for one, the 15-year-old Arata. The only problem is, Arata is actually a male! Forced to disguise himself and take the place of the princess candidate until a formal one can be found, he attends the festival only to witness the current princess, Kokuri-hime, murdered, and his own life is forfeit as well, by the hands of the princess' personal guard, the 12 Shinshou. As he runs for his life, Kannagi of the 12 convinces everyone that Arata is the one who has murdered the princess instead, and now everyone in the Imperial Court is after his head! Now, another Arata from our world has crossed over in Arata's place! How did this happen, and how will these two survive?

A Japanese boy named [Arata Hinohara](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Arata_Hinohara) is transmigrated into a fantasy world and takes the place of another boy named [Arata](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Arata), who was framed for the apparent murder of [Princess Kikuri](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Kikuri), the ruler of the [Amawakuni](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Amawakuni) kingdom. She was in fact betrayed by [Kannagi](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Kannagi), a member of her own personal guard, the [Twelve Shinshou](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Twelve_Shinshou), who all wield powerful swords called [Hayagami](https://aratakangatari.fandom.com/wiki/Hayagami) that are actually gods in sword-form. It's subsequently revealed that Princess Kikuri was not actually dead but in a catatonic state.

The manga began in 2008 and has over two hundred chapters. An [anime adaptation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2703706/) premiered in 2013.

Comment: Yes! omg this is definitely it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @pinkvelvet0 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.